# jScrollPane: when i call to reinitialise(), doesn't create jspVerticalBar div in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

i have a div with some content when the page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.content').jScrollPane();
</script>
<div class="content">
    <p id="p2">some html</p>
</div>
```

and i wait to the user make a click in some button in order to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function userclick() {
        $("#p2").html('');
        $("#p2").append('some html like divs, span, etc...');
        var pane = $('.content').jScrollPane();
        pane.data('jsp').reinitialise();
    }
</script>
```

works well in FF, opera and even IE.

the div is larger and show it the scroll bar, but in chrome, the div show the content but not the scroll bar, so there is not possibility to scroll down.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and that was causing because the table inside the scrollable div was having "table-layout:fixed;".I just removed it and its working. This may help if anyone get this issue.